# Powershell - after a count how to trim line

Tags: powershell

I am using the following to get count from netstat but the count appears on the next line. Here is what I am doing

```
$LIST = (netstat -an|select-string 443|select-string "LISTENING").count
write "LISTENING:" $LIST >> D:\entNew.txt
```

output is:

```
LISTENING: 40
```

How do I get the output to write like this :

```
LISTENING:40
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case just test :

"LISTENING:$LIST" >> D:\entNew.txt

However, I would not use `>>` but `set-content` CmdLet, and I'd prefer use a regular expression to filter the output of netstat.

Comment: Of course Frode you're right. @user3557869 you can put it as answered ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner that I did to test solutions that results in what you want.

```
"Listening:$((netstat -an | select-string "Listening").count)"
```

Comment: :( So I did. I re-wrote it to be more concise.